# Acumatica - Sales Order add notes per line item

Tags: customization, acumatica, bigcommerce

I'm customizing the Sales Order screen in Acumatica to add notes based on the product modifiers from eCommerce, below is the piece of code I grab from previous customization.

I

public virtual void SaveBucketImport(BCSalesOrderBucket bucket, IMappedEntity existing, String operation, SaveBucketImportDelegate baseMethod)
{
MappedOrder order = bucket.Order;

```
  for (int i = 0; i < (order.Extern.OrderProducts?.Count ?? 0); i++)
  {
    OrdersProductData data = order.Extern.OrderProducts[i];
    SalesOrderDetail detail = order.Local.Details.Where(x => x.Delete != true).Skip(i).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
    if(detail != null)
    {
      // HERE TO ADD NOTES PER LINE
   
    }
  }
}
```

I tried  PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(sender, data, option.DisplayName) but still not working

I already debug and try to add PXCache but its seems not working

Comment: are you calling Save action?

Comment: If that field is visible in the SO Screen do you have the CommitChanges property set to True?